# Is "ceased away" instead of "passed away" correct?

Tags: expressions

For example "I am sorry to inform you that my beloved wife Susanne ceased away!". I am not sure why, but I remembered this instead of "passed away", but I cannot find the expression with google.

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't end an "I'm sorry to inform you..." sentence with an exclamation mark, it makes it sound like you're not taking the sad news seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Passing away* means to continue elsewhere. Ceasing means to end and be finished.

To *pass away* is a euphemism for dying. to *Cease* is to end, finish, be complete.

to **pass away** was coined at a time and place, that is, the 15th century in England, when most people would have believed that the departing of the soul of a dead person was a literal physical event. Indeed, 'passing away' didn't mean dying as it does now. When wakes were held for recently deceased people the attendees believed that the dead person could hear and comprehend everything that was being said: it was only later, when the funeral rites were complete, that the dead person 'passed away' and began the journey toward either Heaven or Hell.
As such, 'pass away' wouldn't have been considered euphemistic but merely a literal description of events.
from phrases.org.uk

"Ceasing" is grammatically incorrect as a substitute for "passing". Once ceased there is no "away" to go to.